# Getting an error with Redux-toolkit , "The object notation for `createSlice.extraReducers` has been removed

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I am trying to use redux-toolkit to store data from an api.I tried it but I am getting this error saying "The object notation for `createSlice.extraReducers` has been removed. Please use the 'builder callback' notation instead" Here's the code snippet:

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const getAllJobs=createAsyncThunk("jobDetails",async ()=>{
    const data = await fetch(" http://localhost:3031/jobs");
    const result = data.json();
    return result
    
})


export const jobDetails=createSlice({
    name:"jobDetails",
    initialState:{
        jobs:[],
        loading:false,
        error:null,
    },
    extraReducers:{
        [getAllJobs.pending]: (state)=>{
            state.loading=true;
        },
        [getAllJobs.fulfilled]: (state,action)=>{
            state.loading=false;
            state.jobs=action.payload;
        },
        [getAllJobs.rejected]: (state,action)=>{
            state.loading=false;
            state.error=action.payload;
        },
    },
})


export default jobDetails.reducer;
```

and for store

```
import {configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import  jobDetails  from '../features/jobSlice'


export const store= configureStore({
    reducer: {
        app: jobDetails
    },
})
```

I am trying to store fetched api data to jobs

Comment: I tried searching for the error but those solution suggests using builder callback which I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The object syntax for `createSlice.extraReducers` has been [deprecated since version 1.9.0](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/2301) and then removed in v2.0.0. It's explained both in [v2.0.0 changelogs](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/releases/tag/v2.0.0) and in the [migration guide to RTK 2.0 and Redux 5.0](https://redux.js.org/usage/migrations/migrating-rtk-2#object-syntax-for-createsliceextrareducers-and-createreducer-removed) how to fix it. As the error says, you have to convert the object into the builder callback syntax:

> As an example, this:
>
> ```js
> const todoAdded = createAction('todos/todoAdded')
>
> createReducer(initialState, {
>   [todoAdded]: (state, action) => {}
> })
>
> createSlice({
>   name,
>   initialState,
>   reducers: {
>     /* case reducers here */
>   },
>   extraReducers: {
>     [todoAdded]: (state, action) => {}
>   }
> })
> ```
>
> should be migrated to:
>
> ```js
> createReducer(initialState, builder => {
>   builder.addCase(todoAdded, (state, action) => {})
> })
>
> createSlice({
>   name,
>   initialState,
>   reducers: {
>     /* case reducers here */
>   },
>   extraReducers: builder => {
>     builder.addCase(todoAdded, (state, action) => {})
>   }
> })
> ```

In the future, please make sure to search in the changelogs to seek for examples when encountering an error like this.

Comment: Good answer!
But, "In the future, please make sure to search in the changelogs to seek for examples when encountering an error like this." shouldn't be part of this answer.